# Hibernate query using criteria and projections

Tags: sql, oracle, hibernate

I have a SQL query like this

```
SELECT DESTINATION_NAME, IG_ID, COUNT(FORMATS) AS "NUMBER_OF_FORMATS" FROM 
requests GROUP BY DESTINATION_NAME, IG_ID
```

I am using hibernate and trying to build a query using criteria.

```
session.createCriteria(MyTable.class)
.setProjection(Projection.projectionList()
.add(Projections.rowCount() 
.add(Projections.groupProperty("destinationName") 
.add(Projections.groupProperty("igId")
 )
.list()
```

I am not sure how to count number of formats here. Projection.rowCount() wont serve the purpose. How should i modify my criteria?

Comment: Just figured out 

.add(Projections.rowCount(), "format") should serve the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Projections.count(propertyName)](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html#count%28java.lang.String%29) instead:

```
session.createCriteria(MyTable.class)
    .setProjection(Projection.projectionList()
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("destinationName") 
    .add(Projections.groupProperty("igId")
    .add(Projections.count("format") 
)
.list()
```